# Evaluating model with categorical target variables

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I converted all the numeric target variables of MNIST dataset into categorical variables. So, `0` became `zero`, and so on. Next, I tried the following model on this dataset:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

sgd_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(random_state=42))
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I try `sgd_clf.predict(X_test)`, I get an array of categorical values. I want to understand how to evaluate my model since `confusion_matrix` is not working on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your categorical outputs back into their numeric equivalents, and then use the confusion matrix and normal

Comment: Definitely, but what if I don't want to. Let me explain, this is for educational purpose. I have gone through numerous tutorials where they will tell you how to handle categorical variables, but those are almost always for independent variables. I have never seen anyone teach what should we do in case the dependent variable is categorical.

Comment: Linear models like Logistic regression assume that the dependent variable is continuous

Comment: @WBM How do you figure that logistic regression assumes a continuous dependent variable?

Comment: I'd push you to this response https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266932/in-linear-regression-why-does-the-response-variable-have-to-be-continuous